# To find the combinational coefficients of vectors in polynomials

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Simply put, I have a few vectors of polynomials $\{d_i\}$ and I know one of their combinations gives $x$, which is also a vector of polynomials. How do I find the combinational coefficients $a_i$, namely,
$$x=\sum_i a_id_i .$$

To be precise, the vectors of polynomials $\{d_i\}$ in question constitute the generating set of the kernel of a map $\psi$ (defined below), which is a (sub)module of the free module $M$ in polynomial ring $R$.
Consider that they are known beforehand.
Then for another element of the kernel, $x$, one needs to find the proper combinational coefficients.

I am not familiar with the ring theory either the module of syzygies.
But I am doing some practical calculations which involve the first module of syzygies.
For a given (multivariable) polynomial ring $R$, I understand that the first module of syzygies is related to the kernel of the following map (eg. consider the case with four generators)
$$\psi: R^4\to R $$
$$c_1r_1+c_2r_2+c_3r_3+c_4r_4 \mapsto r$$
where $r_1,\cdots,r_4$ are four given elements of the polynomial ring, and the four coefficients $c_i$ are arbitrary coefficients, also polynomials. As discussed above, $r_i$ serve as the generators of an ideal, and by definition, the map constitutes a free module.
Furthermore, the first [module of syzygies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_syzygy_theorem) is defined as the kernel of the above map, which is a submodule.
My question is about how to find the expansion coefficients of an element $x$ belong to the kernel in terms of its generating set $\{d_i\}$. It seems to be a rather rudimental task but I have no idea how it might work. Many thanks in advance!

---

Below, I give explicitly what I need to solve and what I have tried.
The generating set $\{d_j\}$ ($j=1,\cdots,6$) consists of six four-component ``vectors'' of polynomials in six variables $D_i$ and $D_{i'}$ ($i'$ is denoted by $Pi$ below) with $i=1,2,3$.

```
d1 = {(1 - Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, P1]), 0,   0, -(1 - Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 3])};
d2 = {Subscript[D, 3] - Subscript[D, P1] Subscript[D, P2], -(Subscript[D, P1] - Subscript[D, 3] Subscript[D, 2]),    0, -Subscript[D, 3] (1 - Subscript[D, P2] Subscript[D, 2])};
d3 = {Subscript[D, 1] - Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P2], -(Subscript[D, P3] - Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, 2]), -(1 - Subscript[D, P2] Subscript[D, 2]), 0};
d4 = {Subscript[D, 1] (Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, 3] - 1), 0, -(Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 3] - 1), 0};
d5 = {0, -(Subscript[D, P1] Subscript[D, 1] - 1), 0, -(Subscript[D, 3] Subscript[D, 1] - Subscript[D, P2])};
d6 = {(1 - Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, 3]), 0, -(Subscript[D, P1] - Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 3]), -(1 - Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, 3])};
```

Now I need to find the combinational coefficients $a_i$ so that
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^6 a_i d_i ,$$
where

```
x = {Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P3] - Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P1] Subscript[D, 1] - Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, P1] Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P3] + Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, P1] Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P1] Subscript[D, 1], 0, -(Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 2] - Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, P1] - Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P1] Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 2] + Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P1] Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D,       P1]), -(Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P3] - Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, P1] Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P3] -    Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 1] + Subscript[D, P3] Subscript[D, P1] Subscript[D, 1]Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 1])};
```

One may solve the above problem straightforwardly.
But as explained above, the problem is closely associated with the one regarding the first module of syzygies, and I am not sure a general solution is related.
Therefore I also present them here.
Consider an ideal generated by following four polynomials

```
r1 = (-1 + Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 3]); 
r2 = (-1 + Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, P1]);
r3 = (-Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, 3] + Subscript[D, P2]); 
r4 = (-Subscript[D, 1] + Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, 3] Subscript[D, P3]);
```

When linearly combined with four arbitrary polynomial coefficients $c_i$, the resultant expression
$$\sum c_ir_i$$
is also a polynomial, which corresponds to a map
$$R^4\to R .$$
Now, the kernel of the above map can be derived through the Grobner basis $G=\{g_i\}$ of these polynomials, which can be obtained (without awareness of the details) by the *Mathematica* command **GroebnerBasis[]**.

```
GroebnerBasis[{(-1 + Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, 2] Subscript[D, 3]), (-1 + Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, P1]), (-Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, 3] + Subscript[D, P2]), (-Subscript[D, 1] + Subscript[D, 1] Subscript[D, 3] Subscript[D, P3])}, {Subscript[D, 1], Subscript[D, 2], Subscript[D, 3], Subscript[D, P1], Subscript[D, P2], Subscript[D, P3]}]
```

To obtain the coefficients $a_i$, I tried the command **PolynomialReduce[]** to expand the $x$ in both $D_i$ ($D_{i'}$) and individual vector component (assigned by artificial variable $A_i$), as follows

```
DSixBases = {d1[[1]] A1 + d1[[2]] A2 + d1[[3]] A3 + d1[[4]] A4, d2[[1]] A1 + d2[[2]] A2 + d2[[3]] A3 + d2[[4]] A4, d3[[1]] A1 + d3[[2]] A2 + d3[[3]] A3 + d3[[4]] A4, d4[[1]] A1 + d4[[2]] A2 + d4[[3]] A3 + d4[[4]] A4, d5[[1]] A1 + d5[[2]] A2 + d5[[3]] A3 + d5[[4]] A4, d6[[1]] A1 + d6[[2]] A2 + d6[[3]] A3 + d6[[4]] A4}
PolynomialReduce[x[[1]] A1 + x[[2]] A2 + x[[3]] A3 + x[[4]] A4, DSixBases, {Subscript[D, 1], Subscript[D, 2], Subscript[D, 3], Subscript[D, P1], Subscript[D, P2], Subscript[D, P3], A1, A2, A3, A4}]
```

However, it does not seem to work.

Comment: For the "But instead, I need ...." part near the end of your post, can you give an example input and desired output?

Comment: The question is quite clear and well written by the way, nice job.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will update the question. @MariusLadegårdMeyer

Comment: This is an interesting question. Please edit so I can fix my downvote (meant to upvote and apparently hit wrong arrow, noticed too late to fix).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using Groebner bases but it involves either a bit of undocumented functionality or some digging through past posts to code a module GB.

First I set up the inputs, and use new variables to convert vectors to an equivalent form. The idea is to create a module basis, where each column corresponds to a new variable.

```
polymat = {{(1 - dD[1] dD[p1]), 0, 0, -(1 - dD[1] dD[2] dD[3])},
   {dD[3] - dD[p1] dD[p2], -(dD[p1] - dD[3] dD[2]), 
    0, -dD[3] (1 - dD[p2] dD[2])},
   {dD[1] - 
     dD[p3] dD[p2], -(dD[p3] - dD[1] dD[2]), -(1 - dD[p2] dD[2]), 0},
   {dD[1] (dD[p3] dD[3] - 1), 0, -(dD[1] dD[2] dD[3] - 1), 0},
   {0, -(dD[p1] dD[1] - 1), 0, -(dD[3] dD[1] - dD[p2])},
   {(1 - dD[p3] dD[3]), 
    0, -(dD[p1] - dD[2] dD[3]), -(1 - dD[p3] dD[3])}};
wvars = Array[w, Length[polymat[[1]]]];
newpolys = polymat . wvars;

xvec = {dD[2] dD[p3] dD[p3] - dD[2] dD[p3] dD[p3] dD[p1] dD[1] - 
    dD[2] dD[1] dD[p1] dD[p3] dD[p3] + 
    dD[2] dD[1] dD[p1] dD[p3] dD[p3] dD[p1] dD[1], 
   0, -(dD[p3] dD[2] dD[2] - dD[p3] dD[2] dD[2] dD[1] dD[p1] - 
      dD[p3] dD[p1] dD[1] dD[2] dD[2] + 
      dD[p3] dD[p1] dD[1] dD[2] dD[2] dD[1] dD[p1]), -(dD[2] dD[
        p3] dD[p3] - dD[2] dD[p1] dD[1] dD[p3] dD[p3] - 
      dD[p3] dD[2] dD[2] dD[1] + 
      dD[p3] dD[p1] dD[1] dD[2] dD[2] dD[1])};
targetpoly = xvec . wvars;
```

Now we compute a Groebner basis for this. To force it to effectively preserve module structure, we do not allow multiplication of the module variables. This can be done using the undocumented `DegreeBound->{dvec,dval}` option as below. It works by taking dot product of the vector part `dvec` with the exponent vector of a given monomial, and enforcing that this be no greater than `dval`.

Another wrinkle is that we will want the (not uniquely defined) conversion matrix that takes input polynomials to GB. For this there is a resource function `ExtendedGroebnerBasis`.

```
vars = Variables[{polymat, xvec}];
{gb, cmat} = 
  ResourceFunction["ExtendedGroebnerBasis"][newpolys, 
   Join[wvars, vars], 
   DegreeBound -> {Join[ConstantArray[1, Length[wvars]], 
      ConstantArray[0, Length[vars]]], 1}];
```

Check that we do get the desired conversion.

```
In[278]:= cmat . newpolys - gb // Expand

(* Out[278]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Now we use `PolynomialReduce` to get a rewrite of the target in terms of the GB elements.

```
{mults, red} = 
 PolynomialReduce[targetpoly, gb, Join[wvars, vars]]

(* Out[275]= {{dD[2]^2 dD[p3] - dD[1] dD[2]^2 dD[p1] dD[p3], 0, 
  dD[2]^2 dD[p3]^2 - dD[1] dD[2]^2 dD[p1] dD[p3]^2, -dD[2] dD[p3]^2 + 
   dD[1] dD[2] dD[p1] dD[p3]^2, 
  0, -dD[2] dD[p1] dD[p3]^2 + dD[1] dD[2] dD[p1]^2 dD[p3]^2}, 0} *)
```

We see that this was a full rewrite, meaning no remainder (second value is zero). But we will check explicitly that the rewrite equation works.

```
In[279]:= mults . gb - targetpoly // Expand

(* Out[279]= 0 *)
```

We can put all this together to get the polynomial coefficients needed to represent the target in terms of the original vectors.

```
coeffs = Expand[mults . cmat]

(* Out[292]= {dD[2]^2 dD[p2] dD[p3]^2 - 
  dD[1] dD[2]^2 dD[p1] dD[p2] dD[p3]^2, -dD[1] dD[2]^2 dD[p3]^2 + 
  dD[1]^2 dD[2]^2 dD[p1] dD[p3]^2 + dD[2] dD[p3]^3 - 
  dD[1] dD[2] dD[p1] dD[p3]^3, 
 dD[2]^2 dD[3] dD[p3]^2 - dD[2] dD[p1] dD[p3]^2 - 
  dD[1] dD[2]^2 dD[3] dD[p1] dD[p3]^2 + 
  dD[1] dD[2] dD[p1]^2 dD[p3]^2, -dD[2]^2 dD[p3] + 
  dD[1] dD[2]^2 dD[p1] dD[p3], 0, -dD[1] dD[2]^2 dD[p3] + 
  dD[1]^2 dD[2]^2 dD[p1] dD[p3] + dD[2] dD[p3]^2 - 
  dD[1] dD[2] dD[p1] dD[p3]^2 - dD[2]^2 dD[p2] dD[p3]^2 + 
  dD[1] dD[2]^2 dD[p1] dD[p2] dD[p3]^2} *)
```

These are the `a1,...,a6` that were sought.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! So if I understood correctly, one first finds the *module* Grobnber basis, which is given in terms of the linear combinations of the d_i, and then reduces the target polynomial in terms of the obtained basis, and therefore the resultant matrix product of expansion coefficients gives the desired expansion coefficients. Also, I took the liberty to fix a minor typo and removed a few blanks.

Comment: That seems about right. Thanks for catching the `d`-->`a` error.